# Supporting Large Quantity of Images

Tags: android, image, android-fragments

I'm developing an AudioBook-type App, It need to have some images, and show some text, and the text will be highlighted when the 'voice', starts speaking and so.

But My problem, are the Images, I've around 21 images, each image, represents a page:
My first approach was to use a ViewPager to simulate the book transition, but when In the 13th page, the app just simply would crash. With 'OutOfMemoryError'.
My second approach was to use a FrameLayout to hold the fragments, but just as in ViewPager, the app crashed at 14th page, with the same error 'OutOfMemoryError', the images are about 300kb - 500kb MAX.

Don't know why is this happening, I'm using '`replace`' method of the `FragmentTransaction` to do the fragment replace. And with the `MediaPlayer` for Audio playback I use '`release`' on every `onPause` method..

Thank you very much Guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are not correctly handling the images and if they are not scaled properly you get an OutofMemory. Instead of trying to get it to work for a certain device and then it crashes on another, I recommend you use: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader which will help prevent this error and is very simple to implement.

Comment: I'm using a scaleType of fitXY on ImageView, that isn't correct?

Comment: No because the way Android scales images, you end up loading the whole bitmap into memory, so if you were to do this you have to do a bunch of stuff of only giving the ImageView a bitmap of a certain resolution, but it is much easier to just use that library. Used it before, very easy to use and saves you in the end.